# How to make spell check work for text inside a XML file?

Tags: spell-checking

Editing a Qt localization file, which actually is a XML.
I'd like to check spelling for a text inside tags, so executed a command `setlocal spell spelllang=fr`
After that only attribute value become highlighted as wrong in the first line as you can see on the screen shot.

How to make this work as expected?

[image: screen shot]

**Update:**  Works with vim 8.2.0076.

Comment: It works for me for english and russian. What is your vim version, what is filetype? Did you download french spell files?

Comment: @MaximKim, Vim version is `8.1 (2018 May 18) Included patches: 1-2372`.  My editor detects this TS file based on extension as TYPESCRIPT, so I swith to XML filetype manually with `set filetype=xml`, but this does not help.

Comment: I use the latest 8.1.2418 and for me it works. Are you sure you have downloaded french spell file?

Comment: just to dblcheck you have fixed `xml.vim`, open it with `:find $VIMRUNTIME/**/syntax/xml.vim` and check if there is `syn spell toplevel` on line 60.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Spellchecking inside tags has been requested [some time ago](https://github.com/chrisbra/vim-xml-runtime/issues/19) (and apparently was a long outstanding Debian wishlist bug) and was enabled in the vim-xml syntax file since [this commit](https://github.com/chrisbra/vim-xml-runtime/commit/96e2698663feaa2d471de2e1d3410af63841d7e5). Just clone the runtime files inside your package directory and it should readily work.

The soon to be awaited Vim 8.2 release already contains this commit and should then work as expected.

Comment: It is already available for windows builds https://github.com/vim/vim-win32-installer/releases, btw :)

Comment: aaand I found your name there, so you know that of course. Thanks for providing daily vim builds!

Comment: @taro If this answer answers your question please make sure to mark it as accepted using the accept button under the downvote button. This will help future users to know that the answer worked for you and they can use it too. And if that doesn't answer your question please add details on what you are missing.

Comment: @MaximKim thanks for the nice words :)

Comment: Upgraded vim to version 8.2 and it works as needed.  Thank you!